# Google Chrome keeps disabling a search engine shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, search-engines

I recently changed my pc and I was always using the press tab to search on a site feature of chrome.
I imported all my settings through the google account thingy but for whatever reason I was missing the google images search. I looked through the search engine shortcuts and the one for images.google.com was disabled. I enabled it and I thought that was the end of it but it keeps auto disabling and I have no idea why. It's beyond frustrating and I was unable to find any solution for it. How do I stop it from auto disabling?

Comment: Same Problem with other search engine since beginning of the year. Seems like they won't fix it. Time to go back to Firefox.

Comment: It benefits Google financially, if people use Google more often instead of search engine shortcuts (which often lead to non-google websites)

Answer (score 0):

Well, its called a omnibox. Its like a magic feature.

Well, you can try this : [How to add Omnibox search](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/hidden-chrome-features-that-will-make-your-life-easier)

or this [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chrome/comments/b283zn/tab_to_search_not_working/) if you if that's more comfortable

Well , Sadly it works sometimes and other times it does not.

To make it work consistently, I suggest adding the website in question like for example Twitter as search engine

To do that:

- Go to `chrome://settings/searchEngines`
- Add new Search Engine [image: Adding new Search Engine]
- For **Search engine**, add the name of the site; for example, Twitter.
- For **Keyword**, you can use anything you want. Google's defaults tend to use the URL; for example, twitter.com.
- The **URL** is a little more complicated but not that bad. Go to the site you're creating a search engine for, then search for something. I like to use something easy to spot, like asdf
- Click **Add**, and you're done. You've added a custom search engine to Chrome. Now type your keyword in the address bar to see the text Press Tab to search **twitter.com**.
- Press Tab or Space to search as you would.

Keep in mind this solution requires to manually add your search engines.

[Source](https://zapier.com/blog/add-search-engine-to-chrome/)